# Problems in executing AT commands at modem startup

Tags: c#, modem, at-command

I am developing an application which will read and write data to gsm modem. When i switch off the modem and switch on again, at start up i need to send an AT command so that that modem automatically sets to the settings given for the port. When i give this command in hyper terminal it does not get displayed but the command is sent to modem. and the modem sets itself to the settings that i give for the hyperterminal port settings. From then I can send rest of the commands. But in my application i am unable to send the first AT command, so I am manually doing it via hyper terminal. Why is this not happening through my application? I also tried sending this command using button click, but still it is not executed on the port.

```
        port.Open();
        port.DtrEnable = true;
        port.RtsEnable = true;

        if (port != null)
        {
            btn_connect.Enabled = false;
            btn_disconnect.Enabled = true;
            port.WriteLine("AT");

            port.WriteLine("AT+CLIP=1");

            port.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1");

            con_status.Text = "Connected at " + cboPortName.Text;
        }
```

Port settings that i gave in my application are:

```
            port.PortName = cboPortName.Text;
            port.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(this.cboBaudRate.Text); //9600
            port.DataBits = Convert.ToInt32(this.cboDataBits.Text); //8
            port.ReadTimeout = Convert.ToInt32(this.txtReadTimeOut.Text); //300
            port.WriteTimeout = Convert.ToInt32(this.txtWriteTimeOut.Text); //300
            port.StopBits = StopBits.One; //1
            port.Parity = Parity.None; // None
            port.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"); 
            port.Open();
            port.DtrEnable = true;
            port.RtsEnable = true;
```

Comment: Because thread.sleep() gets executed before all these commands, and then again all these commands get executed in succession without time delay..

Comment: what is the exact number of your GSM module,Impedance of antenna be the problem

Comment: @arunkumarnonascii: When my modem is able to read the first AT command from hyper terminal, why is that it is unable to read it from my application. Guess antenna impedance is not the problem. I have updated my question, please check for the port settings i gave in application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved. Might help some one in the future, this is what I have done.

I added these two lines of settings to my port while connection establishment, which I dint give before.

```
            port.DiscardOutBuffer(); 
            port.DiscardInBuffer();
```

But I have no idea why adding these settings made the difference and solved my problem, but it worked :)

Comment: I would be happy if some body could explain why these two settings made the difference to my port?

Comment: You could look at the source code to SerialPort here: http://typedescriptor.net/browse/types/13811-System.IO.Ports.SerialPort .... your Discard calls are eventually doing a PurgeComm native WIN32 call...that must be resetting the hardware flow control lines....you could try setting your DtrEnable/RtsEnable = true lines to BEFORE the Open.

Answer (score 2):

2 things to check, Baud Rate and Echoing.

The SerialPort class uses 9600 by default.

Normally a modem is in AutoBaud mode, and it will adjust itself to the baud rate of the COM port link when an "AT" command is sent to it. It's unlikely, but your modem might be operating at a fixed BaudRate and won't adjust...thus check which BaudRate you were using in HyperTerminal and use the same one.

Echoing - to see that the commands are sent (and your modem is responding), I believe that you need to turn echoing on in the modem i.e. whatever character you send to the modem and it receives it will be sent/echoed back to you.

(you could alternatively turn on local echoing in HyperTerminal...but you don't want that...you want to really know that the modem saw your character)

**If you can't get the modem to echo back what you send it then you have a problem with the way you have configured the serial port link (i.e. using wrong flow control handshake/parity etc, or haven't raised the flow control status lines).**

Presuming that your modem is configured to use RTS/CTS flow control, have you tried:

`port.Handshake = HandShake.RequestToSend` ? (i.e. hardware control line flow control).

So, it looks like it could be that the eeprom defaults for that modem is not to echo (i.e. someone has altered the echo and done a &W0) or HyperTerminal has been configured to turn it off on the modem when it opens the port to it i.e. it has an AT "Initialization String" !). You should check what the Initialization String is for that port, and copy it/use it when you are using the SerialPort class.

Another best practice is to wait for the response code before issuing the next AT command - a delay is one way to do it but not best practice, because some commands might take differing amounts of time to execute....and some modems do not like receiving another command while it is "busy".

Try this command 1st:

- AT&FE1          (reset to factory settings and turn on echoing)
  (note the &F is unnecessary if you have just switched on the modem as it should be at factory settings at that point anyway....but there's no harm doing it. The E1 turns echo on).
- Wait for an OK response code
  If using HyperTerminal then you just visually wait for the response code to come back if you are typing in the commands (or get your script to wait if using a script to send commands), or if sending the AT commands in code your code would need to capture the response and act accordingly.
- Issue the next command (e.g. your AT+CLIP=1)
- Wait for an OK, ERROR, or a command specific response code.
  Note: different modems may use different response codes even with the same command.
- Issue the next command, etc, etc

Here are some links that might come in handy for reference i.e. show flavours or AT commands, and some HyperTerminal reference.:

- http://www.hilgraeve.com/manuals/
- http://www.stanmex.com/documents/fm_software_docs/HowToConfigureGSMModemUsingHyperTerminal.pdf
- http://www.computerhope.com/atcom.htm
- http://www.howtofixcomputers.com/bb/ftopic78209.html
- http://www.multitech.net/developer/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/S000463C.pdf
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_phone_AT_commands
- http://www.dataip.co.uk/Reference/ATCommands.php

Comment: My modem is in AutoBaud mode, and adjusts itself to the baud rate of the COM port link when an "AT" command is sent to it after startup. I used a textbox to check what data is present on port when im giving these commands. For the first time, tough i try to give the AT command for how many number of times, nothing goes on the port and no response from modem. Then i gave AT in hyperterminal, first it set itself to the baudrate and from the next command there is data displayed on my terminal. So the very first AT command is only going through my hyper terminal and not from my application. :(

Comment: Check the value of BytesToWrite...if it's not 0, then it means you have some kind of flow control issue i.e. the buffer isn't being written out because it deems the serial link/modem isn't ready to receive. Could you also show us the code you are using to initialize the SerialPort.

Comment: `port.PortName = cboPortName.Text;                                    port.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(cboBaudRate.Text);         port.DataBits = Convert.ToInt32(this.cboDataBits.Text);
port.ReadTimeout = Convert.ToInt32(this.txtReadTimeOut.Text);
port.WriteTimeout = Convert.ToInt32(this.txtWriteTimeOut.Text);
port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
port.Parity = Parity.None;
port.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
port.Open();
port.DtrEnable = true;
port.RtsEnable = true;`

Comment: Try doing Thread.Sleep(1000); after the RtsEnable = true;  line. Finally, what values are you using for the timeouts?.

Comment: port.ReadTimeout=300; port.WriteTimeout=300;

Comment: your answer to help me is appreciated. So i am awarding the bounty to you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need time gap between commands...Long back I worked on passing AT commands to modem, I remember passing commands like "AT+FCLASS=8" "ATS0=1" "AT+VTX" in succession without giving any delay in between, are you sure about this delay thing?

Also just

```
 port.WriteLine("AT+CLIP=1");
```

might not work though I am not sure and I don't have a modem right now to try but I think we used to pass an ENTER key as well after the AT command so the command should be

```
 port.WriteLine("AT+CLIP=1" + System.Convert.ToChar(13).ToString());
```

see if changing this helps...

Comment: if it is port.Write(), then you need ENTER at the end. But since it is Port.WriteLine(), you need not pass ENTER. I tried giving the commands without time delay in succession, but they are not working

Comment: Ok that probably is not an issue then...but then I have a feeling its not the delay which is the reason for your problem...try sending just one command and see if it works for eg ATDT command to dial a number...alternatively put break points on each of your port.Write lines and manually simulate delay and check...If its really a delay issue then I think it should not be difficult to add delay

Comment: I have tried sending only one command like AT+CMGF=1 and used a break point too. Its getting executed but do not know why this command is not executed at the port. The proof is i check it in a hyper terminal and there is no change in the setting.